# Why do these sentences take the "as" phrase following the verb?

Tags: grammar, semantics, adverbials

I was learning computer science recently, and I found a expression on books that seems a little bit weird to me.

The first sentence is:

> It's essential to maintain the invariant that all children of a composite have (as their parent) the composite that in turn has them as children.

(the meaning of this sentence is all children regard the composite as their parent and the composite regard  children as its child. )

I want to know why we don't put 'as their children' behind 'the composite'?

The second is:

> Therefore, a class must declare (as a friend) each function in a set of overloaded functions that it wishes to make a friend.

（the meaning is if a class wanna make a function as friend then declare all the functions with same name as its friend. ）

Also, why not put the 'as  a friend' behind 'each function'. That seems more fluent to me.

Comment: It would help if you set out as clearly as possible what you think it should say, and explain why (give actual sentences not assembly instructions). It's a computer science text trying to express complex ideas: it's unlikely that writing flowing elegant prose is the priority compared to trying to be as clear as possible. It's not clear what your preference is for the first sentence. In the second, "that" is (perhaps) modifying "a set of overloaded functions" rather than "each function", and regardless of that, it makes sense to keep "each function in a set of overloaded functions" as a unit.

Comment: Neither sentence is worded well. The "as phrases" are confusingly positioned and obscure in what they mean. The first badly expresses the idea: *In all children of a composite, it's essential to maintain the **same** invariant as their parent.* -- The second expresses the idea: *For each function in a set of overloaded functions, if a class wishes to make a friend, it must declare that function to be a friend.*

Comment: Forgetting about the more complex interpretation of a programming context, the first utterance seems to simply assert *A child must have a parent who acknowledges that child as its own child*. Which seems a pointless thing to say. Perhaps in the programming context it makes more sense if we assume it means *If a class identifies itself as the child of some parent class, that parent class itself must **explicitly** identify the class as a child belonging to it*. Except from what I recall, the "base class" ***doesn't*** have to explicitly enumerate its children, so that's not true anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the prepositional phrase affects the noun phrase that it relates to.

Let’s label a couple of noun phrases in your first example:

- X = “all children of a composite”
- Y = “the composite that in turn has them as children”

The reason for the position of *as a parent* is that the prepositional phrase describes the role of Y. The *composite* that heads Y functions “as a parent” to X (or to each *child* represented by X). That is, *X has Y as a parent* - the role of Y is as a parent to X.

If the prepositional phrase was brought before *have* as you suggest, it becomes a somewhat muddy description of the *composite* that forms part of X. Grammatically, it could even describe the whole X. However, it would no longer describe Y.

Now, you could place the prepositional phrase after Y, but the reader would then need to parse “as children as their parent”. Placing the phrase where it stands in the original provides the clearest expression of the author’s intent, assuming the author doesn’t wish to chop up the long sentence.

Your second example can be analysed in a similar way.